# Pattern matching and processing between two files

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to find all of the different ways to perform pattern matching and processing between two files. I'm new to perl, and could use some help.

I've got two files. `Colors.txt` looks like this:

```
Joe likes the color green.
Sam likes the color blue.
```

`Pencils.txt` looks like this:

```
Pencil one is blue.
Pencil two is green.
```

I need to parse these two files, and print the following:

```
Sam's pencil is number one because he likes the color blue.
Joe's pencil is number two because he likes the color green.
```

Can someone guide me in the direction of how to process this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filecol = $ARGV[0]; # path to colors.txt
my $filepen = $ARGV[1]; # path to pencils.txt

die("USAGE: ./colpen.pl colors.txt pencils.txt") unless -f $filecol && -f $filepen;

my $colors; # hashref of numbers strings for each color string (e.g. $colors->{green} = "two")
my $l = ""; # line by line reading buffer

open(PEN, "<$filepen") or die("Cannot open \"$filepen\" : $!");
while(defined($l=<PEN>)){
    if( $l =~ /(\w+)\s+is\s+(\w+)/i ){ # matches every line that has "... Foo is Bar" while putting "Foo" and "Bar" in $1 and $2 respectively

        $colors->{$2} = $1;

    }
}
close(PEN);

open(COL, "<$filecol") or die("Cannot open \"$filecol\" : $!");
while(defined($l=<COL>)){
    if( $l =~ /^\s*(\w+)\s.*\scolor\s+(\w+)/i ){ # match in a flexible way a first word, then the next word after "color", and put them in $1 and $2

        if( $colors->{$2} ne "" ){
            print( sname($1)." pencil is number $colors->{$2} because he likes the color $2.\n");
        }else{
            print("I have no idea which pencil is ".sname($1).".\n");
        }

    }
}
close(COL);

exit;

sub sname {
    # Just an extra :) for names that end with an s.

    return($_[0]) if $_[0] =~ /s$/i;
    return("$_[0]\'s");

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanations!

nebj00la

Comment: One question: What if there is a case where two people have the same favorite color, and yet there is only one pencil with that color? How would one handle this? An extra subroutine?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Example would be that colors.txt would say something like "John likes Blue", and another line would say "Jill likes Blue". pencils.txt would say something like "Pencil 30 is Blue". I want something that handles the case where "Pencil 30 is John's, Pencil 30 is Jills. I need a function, which from what I've seen could be an array or hash, that says "1. All matched colors to people first. 2. Duplicates found. Ex. Pencil 1 is Joe's because he likes Orange. \n Pencil 2 is Jack's because he likes Red. John and Jill both like Blue, so pencil 30 could belong to either.

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table from one of the files (either one), then look up the desired value when processing the other file.

```
my %pencil_by_color;

while (<$pencils_fh>) {
   my ($name, $color) = /^Pencil (\S+) is (\S+)\.$/
      or die("Syntax");

   !$pencil_by_color{$color}
      or die("Duplicate");

   $pencil_by_color{$color} = $name;
}

while (<$colors_fh>) {
   my ($name, $color) = /^(\S+) likes the color (\S+)\.$/
      or die("Syntax");

   my $pencil = $pencil_by_color{$color}
      or die("Missing");

   print("${name}'s pencil is number ${pencil} because he likes the color ${color}.\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanations!

nebj00la